# Can non-surjective bounded and bounded-below operators approach an invertible operator as the limit?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space. If $\left(A_n\right)$ is a norm-convergent sequence of bounded, bounded-below, but *non-surjective* operators such that the limit operator $A$ is also bounded and bounded below. $\text{Ran}(A_n)$ has fixed dimension/condimension. Is it possible for $A$ to be surjective? Or must $A$ preserve the dimension/codimension? How about on Banach spaces?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Having [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3879500/144766) in mind, suppose $A_n \to A$ in norm such that operators $A_n,A \in B(\mathcal{H})$ are bounded-below and that $A_n$ are not surjective. Then $A_n^* \to A^*$ in norm, where $A_n^*, A$ are surjective and $A_n^*$ are not bounded-below. Since the set of all bounded-below operators in $B(\mathcal{H})$ is norm-open, its complement is norm-closed so we conclude that $A^*$ is also not bounded-below. It follows that $A$ is not surjective.

Comment: @mechanodroid Thanks! Is it possible to get around using the adjoints? Perhaps there can be a more direct approach?

Comment: @mechanodroid But either way, this completes my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4667672/416552). Thanks a lot.